# Storing index - value pairs in a map then check with an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-structures

I have two arrays: data and usedIndexes. First, I need to find all dividable (to another number in the array) numbers and store them with their indexes (let's say in `myMap`) and then somehow go through the second array "usedIndexes" and find **dividable pairs** that one of their index number is in usedIndexes array.

For example, given arrays:
data: `[8, 3, 5, 2, 7, 9, 50]`
usedIndexes = `[0, 1, 6]`

```js
const myMap = {}

  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for(let y = i + 1; y < arr.length; y++) {
      if(arr[i] % arr[y] === 0 || arr[y] % arr[i] === 0 ) {
        if(!myMap[i]) {
           myMap[i] = arr[i]
         }

          if(!myMap[y]) {
             myMap[y] = arr[y];
          }
        }
     }
  }
```

So this will give me something like (index - value pair), `myMap`:

```
{
0: 8,
3: 2,
1: 3,
5: 9,
2: 5,
6: 50
3: 2,
6: 50
}
```

So actual dividable pairs like:
8 - 2
3 - 9
5 - 50
2 - 50

Quite frankly, I am not sure maybe map/object is not the best data structure to hold these values but I couldn't think something else.

Now, how can I loop through the `usedIndexes` array and find key-value pairs which **at least one** of the keys has in `usedIndexes`. Please read the comment in code sample below.

```js
for (let i = 0; i < usedIndexes.length; i++){
 // e.g. usedIndexes first element is 0 and myMap has 0:8 
 // but what I need to return 0:8 AND 3:2 because dividable pair is 8 - 2.
}
```

Comment: Don't store the dividable value in your map, but rather its index (like you already do for your keys of the map). So `myMap[i] = y` and `myMap[y] = i`. You can then easily lookup the values in `arr` when you need them.

Comment: Btw the customary variable name for the counter of the inner loop would be `j`, not `y`.

Comment: I already don't like I am using too many arrays, so looking for a smart solution. I don't care variable name, thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "too many arrays"? You're using only the two given arrays in your code: `arr` and `usedIndices`.

Comment: "*I need to return 0:8 AND 3:2*" - what exactly do you need to return, what should the result value look like? An array of tuples? Something else?

Comment: For the given example in my question. I need the return something like [{0: 8, 3: 2}, ...]. I am making up the result now. The important thing here I need to get dividable values and their indexes as pair. So 8 and 2 dividable and their indexes are 0 and 3 respectively.

Comment: `{0: 8}` - like any object with a single unknown key - is horribly complicated to work with. I'd recommend `{dividend: {value: 8, index: 0}, divisor: {value: 2, index: 3}}`. Do you need only the first found pair as the result or all possible divisions?

Comment: I need all possible divisions.

Comment: Let me tell you a different approach (maybe make things much simpler). Let's say when I try to find all dividable (is this even a word, help :)) values, what if I want to NOT check index values in `usedIndexes` array. I know I've changed the result and what I am looking for but can you come up with a solution for that?

Comment: I've put `if(!useIndexes.includes(i))..` after the first loop (outer) and put `if(!useIndexes.includes(j)...` after the second loop (inner), but I am stuck, it makes billions calls and browser crashes, do you want me to update the description, maybe you can look at?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, is it like the third code snippet in my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't store the divisor value in the map, store its index:

```
const myMap = {};
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
    if (i != j && arr[i] % arr[j] === 0) {
      myMap[i] = j;
      myMap[j] = i;
    }
  }
}
```

Then it's only a matter of going through `usedIndexes` to find those that appear as part of a pair in the map:

```
const result = [];
for (const index of usedIndexes) {
  if (index in myMap) {
    const other = myMap[index];
    result.push([{index, value: arr[index]}, {index: other, value: arr[other]}]);
  }
}
console.log(result);
```

---

However, this will not find *all* possible pair where one value divides the other and one value is referenced by a `usedIndex`. This is due to `myMap` storing only a single pair for each index, even when an index would be included in multiple pairs. (For simplicity I didn't bother to check whether the assignment would override an other value in the first snippet, it only changes whether the first or last combination would be found, it doesn't solve the problem).

To alleviate this problem, we should just get rid of the `myMap` and fill the `result` right inside the nested loop:

```
const result = [];
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
    if (i != j && arr[i] % arr[j] === 0) {
      if (usedIndexes.includes(i) || usedIndexes.includes(j)) {
        result.push([{index: i, value: arr[i]}, {index: j, value: arr[j]}]);
      }
    }
  }
}
console.log(result);
```

---

The only problem with this solution is its inefficiency - `usedIndexes.includes` does iterate the `usedIndexes` array every time. You could alleviate that by creating a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) of indices then use `.has()` inside the loop, but we can actually do better: just don't iterate those indices in the first place!

```
const result = [];
for (const i of usedIndexes) {
  for (let j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
    if (i != j) {
      const [a, b] = arr[i] > arr[j] ? [i, j] : [j, i];
      if (arr[a] % arr[b] === 0) {
        result.push([{index: a, value: arr[a]}, {index: b, value: arr[b]}]);
      }
    }
  }
}
console.log(result);
```

Comment: putting `!` for `usedIndexes` doesn't change the result. `if (!usedIndexes.includes(i) || !usedIndexes.includes(j)) {}`. This should change the result, right? But with or without "!", result always the same. Let's say say usedIndexes = [0, 1, 6]

Comment: @TToprak1 It doesn't change the result for your example input because there are no *un*used indeces that make a valid result pair. It does matter though, there is only one correct choice.

Comment: Still very confused but last question. usedIndex = [1, 0, 6]. When I put the "!" before the useIndexes in the if statement, how even the code goes into that if block. I am explicitly saying if usedIndex has the "i" or "j" do not enter this if block.

Comment: With `if (!usedIndexes.includes(i) || !usedIndexes.includes(j)) {}`, it will still enter the conditional block if one of the two (`i`, `j`) is not included in `usedIndexes`. It only won't enter the block if *both* are included.

Comment: Oh gosh, my bad!